# JS changing attribute based on already set media query

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

In the following code I am trying to change the `dropDown.style.top` with already set media query in the css. Essentially I need once when it's desktop layout the value of the `style.top` to be 4em and if it's in mobile layout (or less than 50em of width) the `style.top` to be 0. I've already tried with match media but I guess I am missing something.
I hope the question makes sense.

Below is the JS function:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  let logo = document.getElementById("logo")
  let header = document.getElementById("header")
  let dropDown = document.getElementById("dropdownMenu")
  let mediaQuery = window.matchMedia(('min-width: 50em'))

  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    logo.style.width = '4em';
    header.style.background = '#000';
    dropDown.style.top = '2.6em';

  } else {
    logo.style.width = '6em';
    header.style.background = '#0000009d';
    dropDown.style.top = '4em';
  }
}
```

Thanks!

I tried using the event listeners for media queries but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I am expecting the dropdown menu once in mobile to fill the entire viewport and once in desktop to behave as normal dropdown menu under the main nav menu.

Comment: You have provided no code that uses media queries. Not sure where the scroll stuff fits into your question?

Comment: You might not need any JavaScript at all. Create a CSS rule that sets the layout for wide screens, and then introduce a media query CSS rule for when the window is less than 50em. Even if you interactively change the width of your browser window, the browser will adjust the layout automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you do not need the following condition

```js
document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80
```

Try this one instead for mobile view:

```js
!mediaQuery
```

### Complete code

```js
window.onscroll = function () {
  scrollFunction();
};

function scrollFunction() {
  let logo = document.getElementById("logo");
  let header = document.getElementById("header");
  let dropDown = document.getElementById("dropdownMenu");
  let mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("min-width: 50em");

  if (!mediaQuery) {
    logo.style.width = "4em";
    header.style.background = "#000";
    dropDown.style.top = "2.6em";
  } else {
    logo.style.width = "6em";
    header.style.background = "#0000009d";
    dropDown.style.top = "4em";
  }
}
```